# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code = EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I am working on to-do list app for iOS. when i build the run the app on my system which i used to development, there are no problems. However when i xcode project on another system.
I get the following error and the app crashes on launch.
Any inputs on what is going wrong?
[image]
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code = EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0

Comment: Looks like XCode issue. I'd suggest updating XCode to latest 4.6.3 version and then run the project.

Comment: try check all xib-files on red rows for IBOutlets.

Comment: first use Break Point and find where to crash is generated ? and also put this code here

Comment: sorted the issue. Had some trouble with references.

Comment: Could you mind answer this question? @newbie

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this while using a breakpoint which would log something and then continue automatically. Disabled that, and things returned to normal. As the message suggests, it's a breakpoint issue